# 500 Error When Importing Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I keep getting a 500 internal error when importing Apps Scripts.  I verified on another app that supports Apps Script import that it is failing there too.

Comment: Obvious bugs are best reported on the issue tracker, along with sample code that replicates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reported here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4049

I'll await the response there.